# PHP eval issue with PHP + HTML code

Tags: php, eval

I've got PHP and HTML code stored in a database table. When I get this data, I need to echo the HTML and process the PHP. I thought I could use `eval()` for this, which works, if I do this `eval("echo 'dlsj'; ?> EVALED ");` I get "dlsjEVALED" printed out.

The problem is, I get a fatal error when I run longer scripts. Things like:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/content.php(18) : eval()'d code on line 1

Comment: The issue is `eval`. Try to avoid it completely!

Comment: You've got quite an exploding mess, haven't you? I suggest you change your code in your database to be full PHP (with, like, `echo '<p>Foo</p>';` instead of just `<p>Foo</p>`). No, actually I suggest you don't use `eval` at all. But it's just me.

Comment: Why on earth would you store PHP code in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that you're trying to eval() something that contains an opening `<?php` tag.  And that leads to the error at hand.

Comment: Correct, I am. But I need to, in this way:
<p>text</p><?php do_php_stuff(); ?><p>more text</p>

Comment: A very ugly solution for the problem at hand would be to write out the stuff form the database to a temporary file, and then load that ...

This would at least achieve what you try to get.

Answer (score 12):

Best advice - never store php and html code in your database. And avoid eval() like the plague.

I can't really tell what's wrong with your code, as you haven't provided enough information. But even if I did have some advice, I don't think I could give it in good conscience.

You should redesign your whole application so that it doesn't require storing such things in the database. I can't imagine why it would be necessary.

Answer (score 12):

just right der...........

```
eval('?>' . $content .'<?php');
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to re-open php mode after the `EVALED`.  [Apparently](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php#96413) you have to do this with `<?` rather than the full `<?php`.

As a rule eval is to be avoided.  But rules are made to be broken.  There's a thread at [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) that gives some less dogmatic advice.

Depending on what you want to do, it might be suitable to use a template file that you source, with text that will vary stored in a local variable prior to sourcing the template.

As for storing code to be executed in the DB... this does happen in some frameworks like Drupal to provide convenient extensibility, but then Drupal is pretty thoroughly scoured for security weaknesses.

Also if you're writing self-modifying code then you need to use eval().  Not sure if anyone has done that in php but it would certainly be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
$contents = htmlentities($contents);
echo html_entity_decode(eval($contents));
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.